# How to detect when all previously registered events in epoll have been deregistered?

Tags: linux, events, epoll

Suppose I register a finite number of events using epoll_ctl within some function. Now, over repeated calls to the same function I deregister every single one of these events a few at a time using:

```
epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, event);
```

How can I tell when all the registered instances have been deregistered?
Do I need to maintain a separate list for this?

**Edit:**

I guess I need to add more context to my question. Assuming I'm able to detect that there are no events registered, then instead of epoll_wait(), I need to perform a certain other essential task within the same function I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you provide even more context? What does it mean that you detect that there are no events registered? If at a certain moment there are not and you do something after the epoll_wait, in the meanwhile new events could be generated and the only way you have of knowing that is by calling epoll_wait again...

Comment: @LtWorf: I'm trying to emulate kqueue functionality in linux. The "other" thing I'm talking about is handling fds for regular files, which epoll is unable to handle. Granted I'm doing all other things before calling epoll_wait. Also, what happens when I call epoll_wait with no events registered but with timer set to -1?

Comment: @LtWorf: But I'd still like to know if it is possible to detect if all events have deregistered. Using this information might just be a minor optimization for my program, but it *would* satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to account for your file descriptors.

If you want to deregister *all* the events, you might just close the epoll fd instead, and let the kernel free the entire data structure (I haven't tried but i would bet this solution is also faster).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added some more context to my question to make my problem clearer. Closing the epoll fd, while it may ensure that all events have been deregistered, won't serve my purpose unfortunately. :)